# How to refresh the registry in powershell after creating a new dword with new-itemproperty?

Tags: powershell, registry

I've just created a new DWORD to be able to [install the RSAT Tools without the Add-WindowsCapability failed. Error code = 0x800f0954](https://www.prajwaldesai.com/rsat-tools-installation-error-0x800f0954)  :

```
> New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing -Name RepairContentServerSource -Type dword -Value 2


RepairContentServerSource : 2
PSPath                    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing
PSParentPath              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
PSChildName               : Servicing
PSDrive                   : HKLM
PSProvider                : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

The `ls HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing` command shows nothing :

```
> ls HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing
>
```

but `gp HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing` shows both the `CountryCode` and my newly created itemproperty `RepairContentServerSource` :

```
> gp HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing


CountryCode               : FR
RepairContentServerSource : 2
PSPath                    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing
PSParentPath              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
PSChildName               : Servicing
PSDrive                   : HKLM
PSProvider                : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry


>
```

However `ls HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies` shows everything including `RepairContentServerSource` :

```
> (ls HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies | Out-String -Stream | sls RepairContentServerSource).ToString()
                               RepairContentServerSource : 2
>
```

Is this normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because `ls` is an alias for [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) which, with registry paths, returns the *subkeys* of the key specified by the `-path` parameter, but not the *values* in that key.

From: [Working with Registry Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-keys?view=powershell-7.2)

> Because registry keys are items on PowerShell drives, working with them is very similar to working with files and folders. One critical difference is that every item on a registry-based PowerShell drive is a container, just like a folder on a file system drive. However, registry entries and their associated values are properties of the items, not distinct items.

To view/display your new item property, use [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item)(`gi`) instead of `Get-ChildItem` (`gci`):

```
PS > gi HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies


Name                           Property
----                           --------
Servicing                      CountryCode : US
```

Bear in mind that even though `gci` and `gi` both display name/value pairs under `Property`, the actual `Property` property is a string array containing only the value names:

```
PS > gi HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing| select Property

Property
--------
{CountryCode}
```

and you have to use [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) or [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) to retrieve the values.